# Can someone please help me understand this query in SQL?

Tags: sql

The tables are from the Chinook database.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0jcm.png)

Q) Retrieve the track name, album, artist, and trackID for all the albums

```
 SELECT Tracks.Name,
 A.Name AS Artist ,
 Albums.Title AS Album ,
 Tracks.TrackId 
 FROM ((Tracks INNER JOIN Albums 
 ON Tracks.AlbumId = Albums.AlbumId) 
 INNER JOIN Artists A  
 ON A.ArtistId = Albums.ArtistId);
```

What I tried:

```
 SELECT Tracks.Name, 
  Aritst.Name AS Artist, 
  Albums.Title AS Album, 
  Tracks.TrackId 
 FROM ((Tracks INNER JOIN Albums 
  ON Tracks.AlbumId = Albums.AlbumId) 
   INNER JOIN Artists A 
   ON Artist.ArtistId = Albums.ArtistId);
```

Comment: what is your output of the query, what is the concern? Also, Aritst.Name wont work, given there is no table 'Artist' or aliased to Aritist. There is Artists

Comment: Please, use [edit], to improve your question, and add info about the error you are receiving. When there is not error, but there is one in this case, you should tell us what your expected output is, and why the query does not match it.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first query is basically trying to join the Tracks table with Albums table to get the album details, and also tracks table with artists table to get the artist details.

Once you've joined all three tables, you are able to get the data track name, album, artist, and trackID from the records.